# Dynamically prepend characters to a String

Tags: java, string

I wish to append a character `n` times as a prefix to my string. Is there any way of doing this using `String.format()`?

Comment: Are you wanting the string to stay this way permanently, or just as an output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use String.format, you can do

```
String prefix = String.format("%" + n + "s", "").replace(' ', ch);
```

A more efficient way is to do

```
char[] chars = new char[n];
Arrays.fill(chars, ch);
String prefix = new String(chars);
```

Comment: Hi Peter ,thanks for the quick answer the only issue with .replace is that my string may have inbuilt spaces in it .. so replacing it with my character wont be feasible

Comment: @muazzamsyed in that case don't call replace() on your string. i.e. like in  my example.

Comment: @muazzamsyed The alternative is to use an invalid character like `\ufffff` but this is uglier still.